# Is there a one-word representation for not advanced?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a one-word representation for "unadvanced" (not advanced).

Example:

```
Advanced and "unadvanced" people do xyz.......
```

Comment: representation?? What in the heck are advanced people anyway?

Comment: Less sophisticated.

Comment: If you're talking about people as a race (biologically, technologically, etc.) then *primitive* is the opposite of advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use the word "novice", depending on the context.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novice

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 'pedestrian'. Following is a link with other synonyms should you choose. (http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pedestrian?s=t)